# Execute Report Data-driven Subscription with T-SQL

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to use the SQL agent job created by an SSRS data-driven subscription to generate a report. Another application uses a stored procedure to insert data. I would like to generate a report immediately after the data is inserted by modifying that stored procedure to execute the SQL Server Agent. My code is follows:

```
USE msdb EXEC sp_start_job @job_name = 'F2B1...'
```

This approach works perfectly when the Agent job is from a standard subscription. With a Data-driven description, the value of the LastStatus column is "pending" for a long while and then changes to "Done: 1 processed of 1 total; 1 errors". I do not see an error in the SQL Agent error log.

Is there a way to do something like this? If so, can I pass the parameters to the report or does it still execute the query defined in the data driven subscription?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the report server logs for what the error is. Data Driven subscriptions do not allow for parameteres to be passed to it.. unfortuatnely. One way around is to create a table that you can load values into and use those values in your dataset query for your data driven subscription

Comment: Thanks! The error was just that I was missing some parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can also kick off a subscription by Subscription ID.

```
EXEC dbo.AddEvent @EventType = 'TimedSubscription', @EventData = '<YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID HERE>'
```

Where the Event Data parameter is the Subscription ID of your report's subscription.

[image]

I actually haven't tried this with a Data Driven Subscription before though.